# sd card photos not displayed when picking them from Image gallery , Android studio,

Tags: android, image-gallery, android-external-storage

I am using this code to pick an image from gallery and display it in an imageView, the problem that this is working just for photos in internal storage, and when I pick an image from my sd card it's not displayed in my imageView

I hope you have a solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView img ;
Button btn ;
Uri imageUri ;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    img = findViewById(R.id.imageView) ;
    btn = findViewById(R.id.button) ;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery() ;
        }
    });
}
public void openGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) ;
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK &&  requestCode==PICK_IMAGE && data != null){
        imageUri = data.getData() ;


        img.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this," you haven't selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

I am using those permissions in my manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Compare the resolitions of the pictures. Report.

Answer (score 0):

I asked and I will answer, the problem was that most of my sd card photos are 2.0 MB or more and they can't be treated directly by the imageView so I added some lines in onActivityResult()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView img ;
Button btn ;
Uri imageUri ;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       img = findViewById(R.id.imageView) ;
       btn = findViewById(R.id.button) ;
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        openGallery() ;
    }
});
}
public void openGallery(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) ;
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
 data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK &&  requestCode==PICK_IMAGE && data != null){
    imageUri = data.getData() ;
    Bitmap bitmap  ;
     try {
       bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media
                   .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imgUri);
       Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 160, 160, true);
       img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
     } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}else{
    Toast.makeText(this," you haven't selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for those who can face the same problem